# Scapy - persistent RandIP

Tags: python, tcp, scapy

I am trying to simulate a TCP communication between two hosts with scapy.

My problem is, that I can't save the random IP addresses scapy generates for me.

This code

```
src_IP = RandIP()

print(src_IP)
print(src_IP)
print(src_IP)
```

gives me an output like this

```
234.200.98.20
147.3.56.17
135.102.142.49
```

So every time I access `src_IP` it has a new value.

Is there a way to save a random IP from scapy? So I could generated 2 IPs at the beginning of my function and use them as source and destination for my TCP communication.
I could generate the IPs myself, but I thought there had to be a more elegant solution to it.

BTW. non of the packets are going to be sent, they will be written into a PCAP file. Therefor I have to create both sides of the communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer is a hack; it is correct (as in "it works and do what was asked"), but it is not the correct way to do that in Scapy.

The method you are looking for is `._fix()`. It will work with any volatile value type.

```
src_IP = RandIP()._fix()
```

If you also need for example a random source port, you could do:

```
src_port = RandShort()._fix()
```

Comment: I never heard about _fix(), but since my python knowledge is limited I might have just overlooked it, or is it a scapy only feature?  

It works!  
Thanks for that  

But one tiny problem I have left is, that my IDE (PyCharm) notifies me that I "Access to a protected member _fix() of a class"  
Is this only a problem with PyCharm or a "real" one

Comment: That's specific to Scapy volatile value API. It is true that a method starting with `_` is considered private, however you can access it. Maybe the method name should be changed to `.fix()`, we'll have to think about it!

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer.
`RandIP()` creates an instance of an object, and every time this object gets accessed, to print or do send a packet or something else, it generates a new IP.

So my solution is to cast it to a string

```
src_IP = str(RandIP())

print(src_IP)
print(src_IP)
print(src_IP)
```

And the output is just as intended

```
232.119.133.38
232.119.133.38
232.119.133.38
```